# Does mailcore support Exchange / Outlook365?

Tags: ios9, mailcore2

Could someone please point me to documentation as to what one needs to do in order to use an exchange account with mailcore? In essence, is an Exchange account accessed over IMAP under the hood and it's only about "automatic discovery" at the point of signing up? Does the same apply to Outlook365? I'm aware the Outlook.com supports OAuth and I've had success setting it up with mailcore but need to understand how Exchange ties up in all this.

Comment: Please take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn440163.aspx

Comment: @DinhViêtHoà Thanks but that is outlook.com (rebranded hotmail.com) and not Exchange / Outlook365. I've been struggling to find something on Outlook365. It looks like a big mess of names between Live, Outlook,Outook365, Azure and Microsoft.

Comment: I don't know much more about that.